# Ember2.8:Toggling the value of a component's boolean variable from a parent component

Tags: ember.js

I have a game-card component which is set up like this:

game-card.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['flip-container'],
  isFlipped: false,
  actions: {
    doCardClick(param){
      this.get('onCardClick')(param);
    },
    toggleIsFlipped() {
      this.toggleProperty('isFlipped');
    }
  }
});
```

game-card.hbs

```
<span {{action 'doCardClick' symbol}}>
  <div id="card" {{action 'toggleIsFlipped'}} class = "{{if isFlipped "flipped"}}">
    <figure class="front"></figure>
    <figure class="back">
      <img src={{symbol}}  />
    </figure>
  </div>
</span>
```

This component interacts with another component called game-handler:

game-handler.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  clickedCard: null,
  clickedCards: null,

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('clickedCard', '');
    this.set('clickedCards', []);
  },
  handleTurn(clickedCards) {
    if(clickedCards[0] === clickedCards[1]){
      console.log('we have a matching pair!');
      this.set('clickedCards', []);
    } else {
      console.log('no match!');
      this.set('clickedCards', []);
    }
  },
  actions: {
    handleCardClick(someUrl) {
      if(this.clickedCards.length === 1){
        //we know the array will have 2 cards to evaluate now.
        this.set('clickedCard', someUrl);
        this.clickedCards.push(this.clickedCard);
        this.set('clickedCard', '');
        //we call handleTurn because we have 2 cards
        this.handleTurn(this.clickedCards);
      } else {
        // we just add the first clicked card to the array
        this.set('clickedCard', someUrl);
        this.clickedCards.push(this.clickedCard);
        this.set('clickedCard', '');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And is implemented like so:

game-handler.hbs

```
{{#each model.cards as |instance|}}
  {{game-card symbol=instance.url onCardClick=(action 'handleCardClick')}}
{{/each}}
```

game-handler is in charge of handling the logic of seeing if two consecutively clicked cards have the same image url. What I want to do now is somehow tell the individual game-card's isFlipped variable to change depending on logic performed by this component.

For example, in the case of a winning pair:

1. We have a winning pair (i.e. two game-cards with the same image URL)
2. game-handler somehow isolates the two cards and passes each a property to trigger a toggle of their 'isFlipped' variable.

Comment: @kumkanillam just added the changes where it says how i'm currently toggling the isFlipped variable. I am currently only toggling it from within the component, but the question refers to if it's possible to also toggle this same variable from the route's controller.

Comment: Only the owner should change property state, currently owner of `isFlipped` property is `game-card` so its advisable to change only in the component...if you would like to change it in controller then you should move the entire game-card properties to controller. this is not good. or else create service and share the state..

Comment: @kumkanillam Taking into consideration what you've said, I've decided to create a new component called game-handler, which will in turn house all the came-card components. I have transferred the code from the controller to game-handler's JS file. Is it now possible to toggle the child's(game-card) 'isFlipped' property from the new parent component?

Comment: what is that `game-handler's` JS file ?. is it normal js file or ember service file ? show us code you have wriiten

Comment: @kumkanillam edited the question.

Comment: No it's not possible, still `isFlipped` property owner is game-card component, you should consider move this property to cards object which is coming from controller `model.cards`. and move flip logic to that controller. thats't reaining things will be taken care by data-binding..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Play.js` route,

I assume, you are preparing cards object in setupController hook, so include `isFlipped` property to every cards instance by the default value with `false`.

Now owner of the cards object and its property is play controller, so change its properties in `play.js` controller so that this changes will automatically propagated to all consumers through data-binding.

In `play.hbs`,

```
{{#each model.cards as |instance|}}
  {{game-card card=instance symbol=instance.url onCardClick=(action 'handleCardClick') toggleIsFlipped=(action 'toggleIsFlipped')}}
{{/each}}
```

In Play.js controller,

```
actions: {
    handleCardClick(cardInstance) {
        //use this clicked cardInstance and do your logic
    },
    toggleIsFlipped(cardInstance) {
        this.toggleProperty(cardInstance.get('isFlipped'));
        //we are chaning particular clicked instance card isFlipped property and this change will reflect it in game-card component.
    }
}
```

In `game-card.hbs`,

```
<span {{action 'doCardClick' card}}>
  <div id="card" {{action 'toggleIsFlipped' card}} class = "{{if card.isFlipped "flipped"}}">
    <figure class="front"></figure>
    <figure class="back">
      <img src={{symbol}}  />
    </figure>
  </div>
</span>
```

You don't require to create parent-component for holding state, you can maintain state in corresponding controller.  on side note,
`this.clickedCards.push(this.clickedCard)` - wrong
`this.get('clickedCards').pushObject(this.clickedCard)` - right
please  consider `get` method to get properties and `pushObject` instead of `push`. if we use `pushObject` only then observers will fire and corresponding template will be updated with new value.

Comment: This is definitely taking me in the right direction. Should I leave my game-card.js the same? or should I remove the isFlipped and toggleIsFlipped action within game-card.js?

Comment: yes, since `card` object and `toggleIsFlipped ` action is available to `game-card` component  through  externalAttributes (which means included attributes while calling the component)